# 3D Reconstruction: Solving Equations for 3D Points from Uncalibrated Images

Tags: computer-vision, linear-algebra, 3d-reconstruction

This is a pretty straightforward question (I hope).  The following is from [*3D reconstruction from Multiple Images*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265190880_3D_reconstruction_from_multiple_images), Moons et al (Fig 2-13, p. 348):

> **Projective 3D reconstruction from two uncalibrated images**
>
> ***Given***: A set of point correspondences `m1` in `I1` and `m2` in `I2` between two uncalibrated images `I1` and `I2` of a static scene.
>
> ***Aim***: A projective 3D reconstruction `^M` of the scene.
>
> ***Algorithm***:
>
> 1. Compute an estimate `^F` for the fundamental matrix
> 2. Compute the epipole `e2` from `^F`
> 3. Compute the 3x3-matrix
>    `^A = −(1/||e2||2) [e2]x ^F`
> 4. For each pair of corresponding image points `m1` and `m2`, solve the following system of linear equations for `^M` :
>    `^p1 m1 = ^M` and `^p2 m2 = ^A ^M + e2`
>    ( `^p1` and `^p2` are non-zero scalars )
>
> *[I apologize for the formatting.  I don't know how to put hats over characters.]*

I'm pretty much OK up until step 4.  But it's been 30+ years since my last linear algebra class, and even then I'm not sure I knew how to solve something like this.  Any help or references would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, this is sort of a follow-on to another post of mine:

[Detecting/correcting Photo Warping via Point Correspondences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384130/detecting-correcting-photo-warping-via-point-correspondences)

This is just another way to try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a pair of matching image points m<sub>1</sub> and m<sub>2</sub>, the two corresponding rays from the optical centers are unlikely to intersect perfectly due to noise in the measurements. Consequently a solution to the provided system should instead be found in the (linear) least square sense i.e. find `x = argmin_x | C x - d |^2` with (for instance):

```
      /           0 \ /    \
      |  I  -m1   0 | |  M |
C x = |           0 | |    |
      |       0     | | p1 |
      |  A    0 -m2 | \ p2 /
      \       0     /
```

and

```
    /  0  \
    |  0  |
d = |  0  |
    |     |
    | -e2 |
    \     /
```

The problem has 5 unknowns for 6 equations.

A possible alternative formulation exploits the fact that m<sub>1</sub> and m<sub>2</sub> are collinear with M so `m1 x M = 0` and `m2 x (A M + e2) = 0` yielding the linear least squares problem `x = argmin_x | C x - d |^2` with:

```
    / [m1]x   \ /   \
C = |         | | M |
    \ [m2]x A / \   /
```

and

```
    /     0    \
d = |          |
    \ -m2 x e2 /
```

where `[v]x` is the 3 x 3 matrix of the cross product with `v`. The problem has 3 unknowns for 6 equations which can be reduced to 4 only by keeping non-linearly dependent ones.

Comment: Thanks!  What I had blundered through was very similar to your first solution.  Unfortunately, the sample points I tried with my solution didn't work out.  I'll have to compare it more closely with yours.  Your second solution looks interesting also.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but I'm still not sure how to proceed.  I see how you got `C`,`x` & `d`.  I know how to solve something like `Cx=d` if `C` is square and invertible., but I'm lost on something like `argmin_x|Cx - d|^2`.  A little but of Matlab code or a link to a good reference would certainly help.

Comment: A solver will usually rely on a QR or an SVD decomposition of the matrix C (see the [Wikipedia article on linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) for details). NumPy provides the `linalg.lstsq` function. I am not familiar with MATLAB, but it seems `x = C\d` should work.

Comment: Thanks.  I was just about to reply that Wikipedia has a fairly understandable article on linear least squares.  And thanks for the NumPy hint - that's what I really needed.